# "ferro se petentem"

Tags: classical-latin, verbs

Valete,

I have this sentence (written by Ulpianus in Digest 9.2.5) :

> Sed et si quemcumque alium ferro se petentem quis occiderit

But if someone (quis) killed anyone else (quemcumque alium) when assaulting with a sword (ferro).

However, I don't understand the word *se* here. It's not reflective as one person kills another.

Can anyone explain the *se*?

Gratias vobis ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *se* refers to the subject of the main verb *occiderit*.

In general, *se* can refer to the subject of the verb whose object it is, or a verb dominating that verb.
When reading a subordinate clause or anything similar, bear in mind that *suus* or *se* can refer to subjects further away.
Grammar does allow you to read it so that someone pursued himself with a sword, but that reading makes far less sense than the alternative.
(For some reason that reminds me of a dog chasing its own tail, but fortunately they do so unarmed.)

Here is a simplification that should make the structure clearer in case someone has trouble parsing the whole thing:

> *Aliquis virum se ferro petentem occidit.*
>   Someone slayed a man pursuing him with a sword.

Here *se* refers to *aliquis*, not *virum*.

Comment: is 'ferro se petentem' a subordinate? I.e. the sentense "Si quemcumque alium quis occiderit" is correct : if someone (quis) killed someone else (quemcumque alium) and about that someone else, the author added : "ferro petentem" (asaulting with a sword) "se" (him). Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @thiebo I'd say it's not really a subordinate clause but "anything similar". The point is that the dominating verb is *occiderit*, so *se* together with another verb can refer to either subject. Your way of parsing the structure is indeed correct. Leaving the *se* out at first and only finding a place for it in the bigger picture afterwards is a good way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

In the Q, adding "him": "...when assaulting him "se" ("him" being the first person, referred to by "quis", which explains why the reflexive pronoun is used, in an indirect statement).

An alternative translation: "But even if anyone kills another, who is attacking him, with a sword...".

If the attacker brandished his sword at a third party; then, a demonstrative pronoun would be used: "...ferro eum petentem quis occiderit…".

A further example: The Romans said that they (i.e. they themselves) would come = Romani dixerunt se venturos esse.

If, however, the Romans said that they (i.e. some other people) would come:

Romani dixerunt eos venturos esse.